# Facebook is not asking the user to provide permission to my site to post on the user's page

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I was using Facebook API's to post content to pages owned by users of my site. Suddenly it stopped working. I read about it and I found out that my app should have manage_pages and publish_pages permissions to post on a page.I submitted my app for review and got those permissions from Facebook. I am using graph API v4.0.
Now while the OAuth dialog, Facebook is stil not asking the users of my site to provide my site for these two permissions. When I try to link my own account through which the app was submitted, Facebook is prompting to provide these two permissions as well and everything seems to work fine.

```
 public function getAuthorizeUrl($reditectUrl,$scope=['manage_pages','publish_pages','pages_show_list']) {

        $helper = $this->fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
        $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl($reditectUrl, $scope);
        return $loginUrl;
}
```

Comment: If these 2 permissions had been approved, did you switch your app to live mode afterwards? What permissions does the Login dialog request from other app users if not manage_pages and publish_pages?

Comment: my app was already live, i asked for these two permissions and they got approved.    In My features and permissions tab, the new permissions are not showed . In Permissions and Features tab the two permissions are showed as approved.

Comment: Sounds like review wasn't fully completed yet then and the contract(s) is/are still pending

Comment: Thanks @lars.schwarz , will look into my account again

Comment: @lars.schwarz ,thanks for the help, there was a contract which was pending